Complex & flatness
Consider $ M_{\bullet}$ be a complex of A-modules and $B$ flat over A. I need to prove (or find the an example, where it does't hold) that $H^i(M_{\bullet} \otimes B) \cong H^i(M_{\bullet}) \otimes B$. If it is isomorphic, I need to find a natural isomorphism.
Any tips how to do it?

Hint: Show that for flat module $B$ and any quotient module $M/N$, $M/N \otimes B$ = $M \otimes B /N \otimes B$. You may need the five lemma.

Flatness of $B$ means that tensoring a short exact sequence of $A$-modules gives a short exact sequence. So if $d_i\colon M_i\to M_{i-i}$ is the differential then $0\to\ker d_i\otimes_AB\to M_i\otimes_AB\to\operatorname{im}d_i\otimes_AB\to0$ is short exact.  Similarly,  $0\to\operatorname{im}d_{i+1}\otimes_AB\to\ker d_i\otimes_AB\to H_i(M_\bullet)\otimes_AB\to0$ is short exact. You should be able to deduce the result now since the last term in the last sequence gives both of the the groups you want to show are isomorphic.

@AndyBaker thank you a lot!
